# Why annotate dupliquates my queryset objects?

Tags: django, django-annotate

Whenever I use Annotate with Case/When logic to return a boolean, the resulting queryset is almost twice as long.

Model :

```
class Message(models.Model):
    readers = models.ManyToManyField(Compte, related_name='messages')

Message.objects.count() // return 495
```

Then :

```
qs = Message.objects.annotate(read=Case(
         When(readers=Compte.objects.first(), then=Value(True),
         default=Value(False),
         outputfield=BooleanField()))

qs.count() // return 940
```

What am I missing here ?
Django 2.2.9 / PostgreSQL

Comment: It's because each `Message` records could have multiple `Compte` records related through M2M so your result is duplicated with same messages but different related `Compte`.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but my goal is to annotate the ```Queryset``` to know for each ```Message``` if a ```Compte``` is among the ```Message.readers```. Can you point me to the right direction ?

Comment: @BenoitCHAUVET: it will make a join with the m2m table, and thus introduce duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this fails is because it will make a JOIN with the *junction table* and then annotate each of the combinations with `True` or `False`.

You might want to use `Exists` here:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

compte_first = Compte.objects.first()

subquery = Message.readers.model.filter(
    message_id=OuterRef('pk'),
    compte_id=compte_first.pk
)

Message.objects.annotate(read=Exists(subquery))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Willem @Charnel, I should have taken a look at the raw SQL to see my mistake.

Now my annotate works fine !

```Message.objects.annotate(read=Exists(Message.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('pk'),
                                                            readers=self.request.user.compte)))```